# Catch error in insert_batch codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I mixed ajax and codeigniter to doing multiple insert.

The code looked like this:

**JS**

```
function save(path){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('members/megumi/container_list/import_from_csv'); ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {path: path},
        success: function (response) {
            reload_table();
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide'); // show bootstrap modal

        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

PHP Codeigniter

```
 public function import_from_csv(){
    $csv = $this->input->post('path');

    $tryOne = array();

    if (file_exists($csv)) {
        $file = fopen($csv, 'r'); // r flag is for readonly mode

        while (( $line = fgetcsv($file) ) !== false) { // if line exists
            $tryOne[] = $line; // add to array

        }
        fclose($file);
    }

    $tryOne = array_map(function($insert){
        return array(
            'CONSIGNEE' => $insert[1],
            'CONTAINER' => $insert[2],
            'SEAL' => $insert[3],
            'THICK' => $insert[4],
            'WIDTH' => $insert[5],
            'SIZE' => $insert[6],
            'COAT' => $insert[7],
            'SPEC' => $insert[8],
            'COIL_NO' => $insert[9],
            'QTY' => $insert[10],
            'PALET' => $insert[11],
            'NET' => $insert[12],
            'GROSS' => $insert[13],
            'CONTRACT_NO' => $insert[14],
            'TGL_TRANSFER' => $insert[15],
            'LENGTH' => $insert[16],
            'GRADE' => $insert[17],
            'NO_URUT' => $insert[18]

        );
    }, $tryOne);

    $insert = $this->container->insert_batch_data($tryOne);
    echo json_encode($insert);
}
```

Let's say multiple insert is failed because there are UNIQUE column in my MySQL table. I got this error on firebug :

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '02NKTL216036109-2-1/8 ' for key 'COIL_NO'

How can I display just an error like this to common user: "Sorry, there is a problem, please check your uploaded CSV".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is modify your `insert_batch_data()` method where you use `insert_batch()` as follows

```
$this->db->db_debug = false;
// .....
 $insert = $this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $tryOne);
    if($insert > 0){
       $test = TRUE;
    }else{
        $test = FALSE;
    }
return $test;
```

Now in controller `import_from_csv()`

```
echo json_encode($insert);
```

this will send Boolean to your ajax. Or you may return any data based on your requirements. So the tricks is hide DB error using `$this->db->db_debug = false;`

You may hide all DB error by using `config.php` where `db_debug` option available to set as `FALSE`

Comment: Nice on on $this->db->db_debug = false. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a TRY/CATCH in your PHP side, this way you can throw an error if the data is incorrect, more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Basically you need to try to perform the upload, and if the data is incorrect it would throw a 'nice' error back to the user...

Comment: Error from insert_batch ci will not work with TRY/CATCH